# Infinite scroll not working on mobile (touch devices) problem

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, scroll

I made an infinite scroll script and it works perfectly on desktop, but it does not work on mobile. I tried all the solutions for related problems here, but didn`t work as well, or give repeated values.

I would appreciate any help

here is my script:

```
<script>

  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#loading').show();

    //Original ajax request for loading first posts 
    $.ajax({
      url: "includes/handlers/ajax_load_translators.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: "page=1&userLoggedIn=" + userLoggedIn,
      cache:false,

      success: function(data) {
        $('#loading').hide();
        $('.posts_area').html(data);
      }
    });


    $(window).scroll(function() {
      var height = $('.posts_area').height(); //Div containing posts
      var scroll_top = $(this).scrollTop();
      var page = $('.posts_area').find('.nextPage').val();
      var noMorePosts = $('.posts_area').find('.noMorePosts').val();


      if ((document.body.scrollHeight == document.body.scrollTop + window.innerHeight) && noMorePosts == 'false') {
        $('#loading').show();

        var ajaxReq = $.ajax({
          url: "includes/handlers/ajax_load_translators.php",
          type: "POST",
          data: "page=" + page + "&userLoggedIn=" + userLoggedIn,
          cache:false,

          success: function(response) {
            $('.posts_area').find('.nextPage').remove(); //Removes current .nextpage 
            $('.posts_area').find('.noMorePosts').remove(); //Removes current .nextpage 
            $('.posts_area').find('.noMorePostsText').remove(); //Removes current .nextpage 

            $('#loading').hide();
            $('.posts_area').append(response);
              
          }
        });

      } //End if 

      return false;

    }); //End (window).scroll(function())
```

Comment: This can be done easier, create a div at the bottom of your page with id="hasFocus" create a onfocus event on the div and the load more items to your post_area.

Comment: but I don`t want to load more items one time only, I have large data and want to load certain number at a time